# Swift- AdMob Rewarded Ad Callbacks to know if the User Watched the Entire Video

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I followed the new [Google Rewarded Ads](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/rewarded?hl=en-US) api for v8 (SDK 8.0.0). The guide is in Objective-C but I wrote the below in Swift.

How do I know if the user fully watched a video so that I can give them their reward and how do I know if they cancelled before the reward should be given?

```
import GoogleMobileAds

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var rewardedAd: GADRewardedAd?

    func loadRewardedAd() {

        let adUnitID = ""...
        
        let request = GADRequest()
        
        GADRewardedAd.load(withAdUnitID: adUnitID, request: request) { [weak self](rewardedAd, error) in
            
            if let error = error {
                print("Failed to load rewarded ad with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            
            self?.rewardedAd = rewardedAd
            
            self?.rewardedAd?.fullScreenContentDelegate = self
        
            self?.presentRewardedVideo()
        }
    }

    func presentRewardedVideo() {

        guard let rewardedAd = rewardedAd else { return }

        rewardedAd.present(fromRootViewController: self) {
            
            let reward = rewardedAd.adReward
            print("Reward received with currency \(reward.amount), amount \(reward.amount.doubleValue)")
            
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController: GADFullScreenContentDelegate {

    /// Tells the delegate that an impression has been recorded for the ad.
    func adDidRecordImpression(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd) {
        print("0. impression recorded")
    }

    /// Tells the delegate that the ad presented full screen content.
    func adDidPresentFullScreenContent(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd) {
        print("1. ad presented")
    }
    
    /// Tells the delegate that the ad will dismiss full screen content.
    func adWillDismissFullScreenContent(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd) {
        print("2. willDimiss ad")
    }
    
    /// Tells the delegate that the ad dismissed full screen content.
    func adDidDismissFullScreenContent(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd) {
        print("3. didDimiss ad")
    }
    
    /// Tells the delegate that a click has been recorded for the ad.
    func adDidRecordClick(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd) {
        print("4. impression click detected")
    }
    
    /// Tells the delegate that the ad failed to present full screen content.
    func ad(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd, didFailToPresentFullScreenContentWithError error: Error) {
        print("5. didFailToReceiveAdWithError: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this [AdMob explainer video from Google](https://youtu.be/xy-AfNcXkJ4), Rewarded videos aren't skippable (min 2:45). Once the user agrees to watch the ad, they can't cancel it.

[image]

As far as knowing if the user watched the entire ad, there is a count down timer in the video (provided by google). When the timer reaches 0, and the X button is shown to dismiss the vc, the callback for `rewardedAd.present` is triggered and that is when you can do something.

```
rewardedAd.present(fromRootViewController: self) {
            
    let reward = rewardedAd.adReward
    print("Reward received with currency \(reward.amount), amount \(reward.amount.doubleValue)")

    print("*** User Watched the Entire Video - Now Do Something ***")
}
```